# Android - Listening to NFC Adapter State Changed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, nfc

I am trying to build an application which uses NFC. The goal is to display a DialogFragment containing a button link to go the settings and change it manually and when the feature is enabled, disable the DialogFragment.

Problem: If the user enables/disables NFC using the icon in the pull down notifications tray , then the onPause/onResume doesn't get called and misses the condition entirely. 
I am sure there is a receiver that I can register to instead and respond appropriately in real time. Any ideas, thoughts or reference will be greatly appreciated!

The following code checks if the state is enabled/disabled. I am also responding to it appropriately in the onResume event.

```
    NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
    NfcAdapter adapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();

    if(adapter != null && adapter.isEnabled()) {
        detector = new NfcDetector(this);
        detector.setListener(this);
        onNfcFeatureFound();
    }
    else {
        onNfcFeatureNotFound();
    }
```

For others looking at this post, the code below will take the user directly into settings to enable/disable NFC:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS));
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thought I should post the answer for other people looking for the same problem, since I wasn't able to find one easily.

Add the following code to your activities onCreate() method:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED);
this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Inner private class declared within your activity (or anywhere else you like):

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ADAPTER_STATE,
                                                 NfcAdapter.STATE_OFF);
            switch (state) {
            case NfcAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                break;
            case NfcAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                break;
            case NfcAdapter.STATE_ON:
                break;
            case NfcAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    // Remove the broadcast listener
    this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}

  // The following check needs to also be added to the onResume
@Override
protected void onResume() 
    super.onResume();
    // Check for available NFC Adapter
    NfcAdapter adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    if(adapter != null && adapter.isEnabled()) {
        createNfcDetector();
        //NFC is available on device, but disabled
    }
    else {
        //NFC Is available and enabled
    }
}
```

Comment: But you're using BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED

Comment: That should of course be: NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ADAPTER_STATE

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ACTION_ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED` to receive a broadcast message when the state of the adapter changes, but that option is only available in API 18 and above. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#ACTION_ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED) for the documentation.

For prior to 18, I don't know of a way to do this unfortunately.

Also, as an aside, the `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS` will work on API levels 16 and above. For prior versions, the NFC settings are under "wireless settings". Take a look at the `ensureSensorIsOn` method at the bottom of [this blog post](http://www.triangle.io/blog/index/4) for a code sample that checks against the API level and redirects to the correct settings pane.

Comment: Thank you very much for pushing in the right direction. I am currently only designing for API level 18 so makes my job a little easier. I have marked your answer right and I will post the solution below.